# Calculating average score for data-points with penalty for outliers

Tags: c#, statistics

I'm working on a product matching feature that works on datasets like the one below:

```
DisplayPixelsX =    1.00
DisplayPixelsY =    1.00
Weight =            0.89
Width =             0.96
Height =            0.96
Thickness =         0.97
BatteryCapacity =   0.92
StorageSize =       1.00
CpuCores =          1.00
CpuClock =          0.68
Title =             0.73
```

The values symbolize the similarity of various product properties ranging from 0 to 1. All those values are currently averaged (weighted) to provide a final similarity score ranging from 0 to 1.

My crude approach of averaging these data-points makes the result less reliable the more data-points are involved. Calculating the average over the sample above results in a score of **0.918** which is by far too good considering the two outliers at the bottom (**CpuClock** and **Title**).

What I would like to implement is an aggregate function that works similar to Average but which gives exponential negative weight to values the further they drift toward zero.

Comment: A quick, ugly way of doing this would be to simply multiply each rating by itself, and apply the same thing to the average. 
This way, only really high-matching values would stand out, as they are much less affected by the calculation, while outliers would quickly drown the average.

The set above would yield a rating of ~0.72, or ~0.85 if you don't weight the final average.

Comment: I'm guessing those are not the real values and you actually rounded them up ? if so, use the real values and only round them for display (or the problem is just on the part of display ?) Could you publish the actual numbers ?

Answer (score 1):

A lot of ways to do this depending on what is "too good" for you. My approach would be calculating some kind of weighted value for each number like this:

```
double value = Math.Pow(value, 9 - (int)(10*(value-0.1)))
```

This code takes 0.91 to 1.00 values as is, squares 0.81 to 90, cubes 0.71 to 0.80 and so on. So the lesser is the value, the less it becomes after transformation. Then calculate the average using these new values. You can change the step or the power depending on what you need